# How to solve ReactJS error in basic component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following error:

[image]

**src/Components/navbar.jsx**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react-dom";

class NavbarComponent extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <nav>This is nav</nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NavbarComponent;
```

**src/index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import NavbarComponent from './components/navbar';

ReactDOM.render(<NavbarComponent />, document.getElementById("root"));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

This is showing up error to me. Can somebody please tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: use. import React, { Component } from "react"; not from react-dom

Comment: Hey, this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the component from `react-dom` instead you should do it from `react` instead.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
```